# How to tell VSCode where to create new Venvs by default

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there's a way for me to tell the Python extension in VSCode to always create new virtual environments in a custom folder. I'm wanting to keep all my virtual environments  for all projects in one folder, rather than having the venv in the project folder for each project. If I create a new venv from within the Python extension (or the Python Environments Manager extension), it always defaults to creating it within the current workspace folder. Is there a way to change this behaviour such that it is always created in my custom, separate folder?

I've tried adding the folder path to Python: Venv Folders and Python: Venv Path. It finds all the virtual environments in my custom folder, but it doesn't default to creating them in there.

Comment: if it is in the workspace VSC will find it so you can select in from the list

Answer (score 0):

If you use the vscode interface command to create a new virtual environment, then the default location is the current workspace (the currently opened folder).

[image]

---

As a way to achieve your goal, you can create a virtual environment using the command in the terminal. Just *specify the new virtual environment path* in the command.

```
python -m venv E:\workspace\venv\env01
```

[image]

The above command will create a new virtual environment named `env01` under the `E:\workspace\venv\` path. You can learn more in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/venv.html).

You can also specify the python version, for example, the following command will use the python interpreter at the `E:\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe` location to create a `env03` virtual environment of the same version

```
E:\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv E:\workspace\venv\env03
```

Then add the `E:\workspace\venv` path to **Python：Venv Path**.

[image]

Vscode will recognize all virtual environments in this folder, and you can select them in the **Select Interpreter** panel.

[image]

*Another option is to use [Anaconda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html). The newly created conda environment will be in the same folder, and you can manage it through the **Anaconda Navigator**.*

[image]